# Using a list retrieved from a SQLite query in a 'foreach' statement

Tags: c#, winforms, list, sqlite, foreach

I'm currently converting some code that stores data in an XML file to storing it in a SQLite database instead. The database has a single table with 4 columns:

`thumbnail | title | threadid | url`

All of the entries in the database are strings. With my old code, I extract all the data from an XML file and populate a datagrid with the values. My aim is to do just that but using data pulled from the SQLite database. I can successfully extract all the data from the database table like so:

```
public List<Database> getFromTable()
{
    List<Database> items = new List<Database>();
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM blacklist";
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
    using (SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var item = new Database();
            item.imgstring = (string)reader["thumbnail"];
            item.titlestring = (string)reader["title"];
            item.threadidstring = (string)reader["threadid"];
            item.urlstring = (string)reader["url"];

            items.Add(item);
        }
    }

    return items;
}
```

The part I'm now stuck on is how to use the results returned in the list. Currently I'm calling the method like so:

`var items = database.getFromTable();`

However after failing to find some examples, I can't work out how to put the `foreach` line together use the items in the returned list. Eg;

```
foreach (??? in items)
{
    // Populate line in datagrid with thumbnail, title, threadid, url
}
```

I can get the datagrid populated, it's just understanding how to breakdown my 'items' into a usable form. Any pointers appreciated.

**Edit** I will be adding this information into a data-grid so each cell value from the SQLite table will be added into a matching cell on the data-grid.

**Edit 2** It's worth mentioning that while `thumbnail` from my SQLite database is a string value, it's actually an image that's been converted to a `Base64ImageRepresentation` so I can store it as a string value.  Part of getting each value from the SQLite database is so I can convert this string back to an image before adding in into my `DataGridView`.

Comment: Where is `m_dbConnection` declared? Looks like you're not disposing of your connection properly. It needs to be wrapped in a using statement too.

Comment: It's in the same class as `public List<Database> getFromTable()`. I'll get that addressed.

Comment: what exactly is your aim? you want to show the values in the `List<Database> items` in a `DataGridView`? " breakdown my 'items' into a usable form" what exactly do you mean by "usable" form?

Comment: I have a datagrid on my form that matches the SQLite table layout (thumbnail | title | threadid | url) and I want the values take from the database, to be inserted into the datagrid. I can get the data from the SQLite database (above), and I know how to populate a datagrid. What I can't work out how to put the `foreach` command together to break down each row of data in my list.

Comment: Do you mean a typical foreach loop like `foreach (var item in items)`?

Comment: there is not `DataGrid` in WinForms. Are you using `DataGridView` ? If yes then why don't you just use the `DataSource` property and bind the list directly to the `DataGridView` this way there will be no loop and populating necessary, all will be done automatically, even the assignment of column headers

Comment: @MongZhu Sorry, Yes I did mean `datagridview`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to forego the custom objects, and instead just read a `DataTable` and use it as the source of the `DataGridView` directly.

If you must use the custom objects, then you will have to loop over them, create rows from the grid's data source, and populate the rows one by one, adding them back once populated.

Something like this:

```
foreach (var item in getFromTable())
{
    var index = grid.Rows.Add();
    var row = grid.Rows[index];
    row.SetValues(item.imgstring, item.titlestring, item.threadidstring, item.urlstring);  //order of the items must match field order in grid
}
```

Still, I would opt for the option of binding to a solid data source.  But this should give you the general idea.